# python doubles backslash and nothing working

Tags: python, escaping

I have problem in Python, it doubles my backslashes. I tried writing `r` before the string and I tried doubling the backslash and it is still gives double backslashes.

When I try to write `r` before the quotes there is only one backslash, but that `r` is there and if I make two backslashes, there are still two backslashes. I tried `r` before it. I do not know what to do. Please help.
Thank you.

Code is here:

```py
import os
lost = []
directory = "D:\Black betty\combs"
combinations = "combinations"
os.chdir(directory)
for line in os.listdir(directory):
    lost.append(line)
for line in lost:
    try:
        otevritsoubor = open(line)
        prvniradek = otevritsoubor.readline()
        otevritsoubor.close()
        souborscestou = "D:\Black betty\combs" + line
        os.rename(souborscestou,prvniradek)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        pass
```

Comment: Tryied it, not working.
https://ctrlv.cz/meFJ

Comment: [WinError 2] Systém nemůže nalézt uvedený soubor: 'D:\\Black betty\\combscombinations4105.txt' -> 'baosp3qq\n

Comment: What window are you using?

Comment: Windows 10. But the directory exist. of course, only with one backshlash.

Answer (score 1):

You neglected to add an extra double backslash before `+ line` and you should strip the newline from the new name.
Here is the corrected code:

```
import os
lost = []
directory = "D:\\Black Betty\\combs"
combinations = "combinations"
os.chdir(directory)
for line in os.listdir(directory):
    lost.append(line)
for line in lost:
    try:
        otevritsoubor = open(line)
        prvniradek = otevritsoubor.readline()
        otevritsoubor.close()
        souborscestou = "D:\\Black Betty\\combs\\" + line # In your previous code, you only concatenated combs and line without \\
        os.rename(souborscestou,prvniradek.strip())
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        pass
```

Comment: Hello, thank you, but t is still not working. I rewrite the file at line otevritsoubor = open(file) to otevritsoubor = open(line) because it told me undefined name file. The error [WinError 123] Název souboru či adresáře nebo jmenovka svazku je nesprávná: 'D:\\Black Betty\\combs\\combinations1102.txt' -> 'uuu8htn\n' is still there.

Comment: add .strip at prvniradek

Comment: Hello, I´ve never used that command, can oyu, please, use it at code? Thank you :)

Comment: Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add double backslashes to your strings. Otherwise it tries to escape the next character. You can also use r before your string if you want to bypass escapes.

`directory = "D:\\Black betty\\combs"`

or

`directory = r"D:\Black betty\combs"`

Comment: Not working any of this solutions. Every two solutions makes double backslash :D